# Error de llenado array con Foreach Java

Tags: java, array, foreach

estoy intentando llenar un array con foreach pero sólo guarda el último caracter que ingreso y el resto del array se imprime como vacío, pueden ayudarme?

Técnicamente imprime un array así     [b,   ,   ,  ] siendo b el último caracter que ingresé.

```
package array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Array 
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nElementos;
        nElementos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Número de elementos: "));
        char[]letras=new  char[nElementos];
        System.out.println("Digite los elementos");
        
        for(char i:letras)
        {
            System.out.println("Digite un caracter: ");
            letras[i] = entrada.next().charAt(0);
        }
        System.out.println("\nLos caracteres del arreglo son");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letras));
    
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas un contador para ir llenando el array, algo así:

```
     for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){
         System.out.println("Digite un caracter: ");
         letras[i] = entrada.next().charAt(0);
     }
```

Luego, para mostrar el array, no hace falta un bucle, porque precisamente `Arrays.toString` te muestra una cadena con los elementos de un array sin tener que recorrerlos uno por uno, basta con ponerlo simplemente así, sin bucle `for`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letras));
```

Si el requerimiento es hacerlo conun `for each` tienes que implementar un índice que se vaya incrementando dentro del bucle, por ejemplo:

```
    /*
        Índice inicializado a 0
        que se irá incrementando dentro del bucle
    */
    int i = 0;
    /*
        OJO: he nombrado cada elemento ch
        por convención de nombre
        mientras que reservo i para el índice
    */
   
    for(char ch:letras)
    {
       
        System.out.println("Digite un caracter: ");
        /*
           Aquí se asigna el valor actual de i
           y se incrementa en 1 con ++ para la 
           próxima iteracción
        */
        letras[i++] = entrada.next().charAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: Sí, pero el ejercicio era llenar el array con un Foreach... Por eso no he colocado con el for sencillo

Comment: @AnnieFernández en ese caso tienes que meter un índice dentro del bucle e irlo incrementando. No puede usar al mismo tiempo el elemento como índice en un `for each`

Comment: Y cómo insertaría un índice sin tener que utilizar ```params```

Comment: @AnnieFernández revisa la respuesta, al final. Supongo que es un ejercicio, pues no le veo demasiado sentido a eso, porque no te sirve de nada recorrer `letras` de ese modo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El loop inicial realmente usa `char i:letras` asignando a `i` el valor de letras[0] (que tiene valor 0 incialmente) por lo que siempre inserta en la posicion 0. Debes usar un indice adicional ya que foreach no tiene info acerca de que posicion lleva en el loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nElementos;
    nElementos = 3;
    char[]letras=new  char[nElementos];
    System.out.println("Digite los elementos");
    int index=0;
    for (char i : letras) {
        System.out.println("Digite un caracter: ");
        letras[index] = entrada.next().charAt(0);
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nLos caracteres del arreglo son");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letras));
    
    System.out.println("Longitud del array: "+letras.length);
}
```

Ademas para mostrarlo correctamente no es necesario hacer loop sobre `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: No funcionó... aún sigue guardando sólo el último caracter ingresado.

Comment: Muchas gracias.